# Android ActionBar Loading Issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I've having an issue with my actionBar that I've implemented.The screenshots below that I've provided will highlight the problem that I'm facing.Currently when I start my MainActivity,I've a navigation drawer and an actionBar.But the problem I'm facing is that there a split-second loading of the actionbar where it's in its original white color as shown below.

[image: Original]

And then it immediately proceeds on changing its color as I've set as shown belown.

[image: After Change]

My issue is,how do I prevent the ActionBar for being "white" for a quick split second before it changes color?How do I let the actionBar be immediately green the moment the Activity starts?Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target for minimum API level 11 , you can change ActionBar's background color by defining custom style, as:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
```

And, set "MyTheme" as theme for application / activity. It will not show that split second problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I've managed to retrieve the solution through the help of your answer.In defining my custom style,I've managed to change the Color and "remove" both the Logo and Title at the same time through the following code.

 <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the color in your activity?
Perhaps you can try using Styles instead?